# Amazon Web Services relational database hibernate

Tags: orm, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I am trying to use the Amazon Web Services, specially the Amazon Relational Database Service (RDS). Currently I can create a database and send some SQL Statements. So everything is ok.

Now I am looking for a ORM framework that work with Amazon RDS.

Does anyone have a good proposal?

Answer (score 0):

RDS is not any different from (whichever database your RDS instances are using), so anything goes.